# Что означает нотация указателя на функцию, создаваемая std::bind?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, отладка

Из отладчика вот такую строку не могу прочесть:

```
std::_Bind<void (SpeechRecognizerPlugin:: *(SpeechRecognizerPlugin *))()>::operator()<, void>()
```

- `void()` - тип функции
- `SpeechRecognizerPlugin::*` - указатель на член `SpeechRecognizerPlugin`

А вот это что такое?

- `(SpeechRecognizerPlugin::* (SpeechRecognizerPlugin*))`

И почему параметр шаблона пропущен перед запятой? Как так?

Пример взят из `call-stack`'а дебаггера. Может быть это особая нотация самого дебаггера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это тип функции, принимающей указатель на SpeechRecognizerPlugin и возвращающей указатель на нестатическую функцию этого класса.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct SpeechRecognizerPlugin
{};

using VoidFun = void ();
using MemberVoidFunPtr = VoidFun SpeechRecognizerPlugin::*;
using Fancy = MemberVoidFunPtr (SpeechRecognizerPlugin *);

static_assert
(
    ::std::is_same_v
    <
        void (SpeechRecognizerPlugin:: *(SpeechRecognizerPlugin *))()
    ,   Fancy
    >
);
```

[Online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:3,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:3,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Astruct+SpeechRecognizerPlugin%0A%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Ausing+VoidFun+%3D+void+()%3B%0Ausing+MemberVoidFunPtr+%3D+VoidFun+SpeechRecognizerPlugin::*%3B%0Ausing+Fancy+%3D+MemberVoidFunPtr+(SpeechRecognizerPlugin+*)%3B%0A%0Astatic_assert%0A(%0A++++::std::is_same_v%0A++++%3C%0A++++++++void+(SpeechRecognizerPlugin::+*(SpeechRecognizerPlugin+*))()%0A++++,+++Fancy%0A++++%3E%0A)%3B%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Параметры вида `, void` получаются, когда вначале идет пустой пак параметров.

```
template<typename... Args>
struct Dummy
{
    using Type = void;
};

struct Foo
{
    template<typename... Args, typename Last = typename Dummy<Args...>::Type>
    void operator ()(Args...)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo{};
    foo();
}
```

Comment: Хм, обычно в таких нотациях указатель в скобки берётся. Это, конечно, запутало.

Comment: Указатель взят в скобки, только они еще и функцию оборачивают, void **(** SpeechRecognizerPlugin:: *(SpeechRecognizerPlugin * ) **)** ()

Comment: А, ну да, я просто спутал тип функции с типом указателя на функцию.